# TypeORM sql dialect agnostic query with query builder

Tags: typescript, nestjs, typeorm

Can I write the following query using TypeORM QueryBuilder to get a SQL Dialect agnostic query?

```js
select *
from mytable
where mycol1 = 'foo'
and mycol2 = (select max(mycol2)
                  from mytable
                  where mycol1 = 'foo');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const result = await getRepository(entity_name)
      .createQueryBuilder("my_table")
      .select("*")
      .where("my_table.mycol1 = :value AND my_table.mycol2 = (select MAX(my_table.mycol2) FROM my_table WHERE my_table.mycol1 = :value)", { value: 'foo' })
      .getMany();
```